# How can I make an infinite amount of posts in PHP without overwriting said post on the same page?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a post request on the same page with infinite amount of posts. The only problem is that the post that I am doing keeps overwriting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="https://wikiscams.org/form.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Anon" name="user">&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

if(isset ($_POST["submit"])) {
    
   $user = $_POST['user'];
  
   // echoes post but overwrites
  
   echo $user;
   
}
?>
```

What should I do?

Comment: you are requesting a "new" page evertime you submit the form. You need to store the data somewhere (like a mysql database) and output it in a loop too :)

Comment: You could put the `$user` into the `value` of `user` then the new value would pass over..assuming user doesnt delete. Also this would be open to XSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTML you can use arrays on PHP side and that's what you need right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


    <form action="https://wikiscams.org/form.php" method="post">
        <?php if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
            foreach ($_POST['user'] as $key => $value) { ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="user[]" value="<?=$value?>">
            <?php }
        } ?>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Anon" name="user[]">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>



    <?php 
        if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
            foreach($_POST['user'] as $key => $user){
                echo $user."<br />";
            }
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @trainrobber If this answer is correct I would greatly appreciate it if you could confirm and vote.